# Scraping stopping at first line

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I need to scrap a website to obtain some information like Film's title and the relative links. My code run correctly but it stops at the first line of the website. This is my code, thank you in advance for your help and sorry if this is not a smart question but I'm a novice.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL= 'http://www.simplyscripts.com/genre/horror-scripts.html'

def scarica_pagina(URL):
    page = requests.get(URL)
    html = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') l
    films = soup.find_all("div",{"id": "movie_wide"})
    for film in films:
        link = film.find('p').find("a").attrs['href']
        title = film.find('p').find("a").text.strip('>')
        print (link)
        print(title)
```

Comment: Tell the website url

Comment: Everything here looks fine.  Sounds like you have a website dependent problem.

Comment: you can post the link to the site and do it by edit your question

Comment: I did it, thank you!

Comment: There's only one `div#movie_wide` with multiple `p`s containing `a`s.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below way. I've slightly modified your script to serve the purpose and make it look better. Let me know if you encounter any further issues:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.simplyscripts.com/genre/horror-scripts.html'

def scarica_pagina(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    for film in soup.find(id="movie_wide").find_all("p"):
        link = film.find("a")['href']
        title = film.find("a").text
        print (link,title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scarica_pagina(URL)
```